# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ITypeRegistrationsProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, enterprise-library

I recently tried to implement authentication using asp.net identity with 4.6.1 framework.
After installing all the required packages I am getting the following error when running the application.

> "Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ITypeRegistrationsProvider"

The same application works fine when all the packages related to identity are uninstalled.

Full stack trace is as follows

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ITypeRegistrationsProvider'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule
>   pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob,
>   Int32* pcNamedArgs) +0
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32&
>   namedArgs) +38
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +571 
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
>   +37    Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, Boolean& conflict) +294
>
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration(String friendlyName,
>   IList`1 errors) +105
>   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName,
>   IList`1 errorDetails) +161    Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String
>   startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +51
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +238
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
>   +103    System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
>   +115    System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +72
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +104
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +352
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ITypeRegistrationsProvider'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947380 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261

It would be a great help if some one helps, I am struck for a week.

please let me know if any more information is required

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Configure the OWIN startup class in your `web.config` / `app.config` `appSettings` like this:

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="-- your startup class --" />
```

### The whole story

The problem has to do with the way that OWIN looks for the Startup class. For some strange reason, it finds `ITypeRegistrationsProvider` and tries to load it.

OWIN has [three ways to look for the application startup class](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection):

- Naming Convention: Katana looks for a class named Startup in namespace matching the assembly name or the global namespace.
- OwinStartup Attribute: This is the approach most developers will take to specify the startup class. The following attribute will set the startup class to the TestStartup class in the StartupDemo namespace.
- The appSetting element in the Configuration file `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="..." />`

If you look carefully the call stack, you'll see that the problem is related to the second one, looking for the attribute: `Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute`. For some reason it finds `ITypeRegistrationsProvider` is suitable as an Startup class, and tries to instance it. Apart from being incorrect, it fails because you cannot instance an interface.

Once you know what the problem is, if you read OWIN source code, in particular [OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/OwinBuilder.cs), you'll see that the first option to find the startup class is to use the one specified in `appSettings`:

```
string appStartup = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.OwinAppStartup];
```

If you specify yous startup class in `web.config` you'll prevent the application from looking and trying to instance the wrong class. So, to solve the problem, you simply have to specify the app startup class in your `web.config` or `app.config` `appSettings`, like this:

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="-- your startup class --" />       
</appSettings>
```

Notes:

- in the linked document you'll see `owin:appStartup`, but if you check the source code you'll see that the right syntax is `owin:AppStartup` ([OwinAppStartup constant](http://OwinAppStartup), as used in the code snippet above)
- you can specify yous startup class in servera ways, but I recommend you to specify it like this "namespace.ClassName, assemblyName" which is the safest one.

If your configuration is right, I warranty that the Owin loader will take your real startup class, and the error will not happen.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I had to add this key as well `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />`

Comment: Update: the solution will work if we add two keys:

`<add key="owin:automaticAppStartup" value="true" />`
`<add key="owin:appStartup" value="--your project--.Startup, --your project--" />`