# Including Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb with enterpise library fails to load ITypeRegistrationsProvider

Tags: asp.net, owin, enterprise-library

I have an ASP.NET application which uses Enterprise Library and is working fine.

I'm trying to include some OWIN middleware, for which I install the [`Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/).

I've created a class and decorated it with the `[OwinStartup]` attribute so that it's used as the Owin Startup class. However, when I start the application I get the exception:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ITypeRegistrationsProvider' from assembly  'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the call stack thoroughly, and I found that the OWIN loader is trying to instance the `ITypeRegistrationsProvider` class, as if it was the OWIN startup class.

So, I look for information about the OWIN loader, and found that it's possible to specify the startu class in tha application settings to avoid the OWIN loader making this error. So, the solution is simply to specify the startup class like this:

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="-- your startup class --" />       
</appSettings>
```

For a deeper explanation you can [see my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619202/could-not-load-type-microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-common-configuration/37025141#37025141).