# Trying to use hangfire with enterprise library fails with "could not loat ITypeRegistrationsProvider type" exception

Tags: asp.net, enterprise-library, hangfire

I have an ASP.NET application which uses Enterprise Library.

When I install the `Hangfire` nuget pacakge, the application refuses to start by throwing this exception:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.ITypeRegistrationsProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

If I remove the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` Nuget package, the application runs fine, but the OWIN startp up class is not invoked, and I cannot use the Hangfire middleware.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic error that happens with some configurations when you try to use OWIN in an ASP.NET application which also includes Enterprise library.

The solution, and an explanation of the problem, [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619202/could-not-load-type-microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-common-configuration/37025141#37025141). In few words, the solution is to configure the start up class in `web.config`'s `appSettings`, like this:

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="-- your startup class --" />       
</appSettings>
```